# jQuery: "$(this)" within click handler not targeting clicked element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanna do a simple class transformation when clicked on an element but when I reference `$(this)` within the click handler it returns `jQuery.fn.init {}` and not the clicked element like I used to. I'm certainly missing something, but I don't know what.

```
const $uspElements = $('.pd-hero__usp');
if ($uspElements.length > 0) {
  $(document).on('click', '.pd-hero__usp', () => {
    console.log($(this)); // outputs: jQuery.fn.init {}

    // Remove active state from all usps
    $uspElements.removeClass('pd-hero__usp--active');

    // add active state to clicked usp (not working)
    $(this).addClass('pd-hero__usp--active');
  });
}
```

HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="pd-hero__usp pd-hero__usp--active">
  <div class="pd-hero__usp-icon">
    <svg class="list-point__icon list-point__iconplate" width="56" height="56" viewBox="0 0 56 56" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">[...]</svg>
  </div>
  <div class="pd-hero__usp-text">
    Text 1
  </div>
</div>
<div class="pd-hero__usp">
  <div class="pd-hero__usp-icon">
    <svg class="list-point__icon list-point__iconplate" width="56" height="56" viewBox="0 0 56 56" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">[...]</svg>
  </div>
  <div class="pd-hero__usp-text">
    Text 2
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you have arrow function `() => {` replace it by `function () {`

Comment: Oh thanks, I wasn't aware that these aren't interchangeable.

Comment: yea, arrow function is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

you should be using `function` instead of `()=>`

```
const $uspElements = $('.pd-hero__usp');
if ($uspElements.length > 0) {
  $(document).on('click', '.pd-hero__usp', function() {
    console.log($(this)); // outputs: jQuery.fn.init {}

    // Remove active state from all usps
    $uspElements.removeClass('pd-hero__usp--active');

    // add active state to clicked usp (not working)
    $(this).addClass('pd-hero__usp--active');
  });
}
```

[jQuery .on() API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 0):

[`Arrow functions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

> An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax than a function expression and does not have its own `this`, `arguments`, `super`, or `new.target`.

From the above, since arrow function does not have its own `this`, you can use `event.currentTarget` instead:

```js
const $uspElements = $('.pd-hero__usp');
if ($uspElements.length > 0) {
  $(document).on('click', '.pd-hero__usp', (event) => {
    console.log(event.currentTarget); 

    // Remove active state from all usps
    $uspElements.removeClass('pd-hero__usp--active');

    // add active state to clicked usp (not working)
    $(this).addClass('pd-hero__usp--active');
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pd-hero__usp pd-hero__usp--active">
  <div class="pd-hero__usp-icon">
    <svg class="list-point__icon list-point__iconplate" width="56" height="56" viewBox="0 0 56 56" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">[...]</svg>
  </div>
  <div class="pd-hero__usp-text">
    Text 1
  </div>
</div>
<div class="pd-hero__usp">
  <div class="pd-hero__usp-icon">
    <svg class="list-point__icon list-point__iconplate" width="56" height="56" viewBox="0 0 56 56" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">[...]</svg>
  </div>
  <div class="pd-hero__usp-text">
    Text 2
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use function(), instead of () => arrow function

```js
const $uspElements = $('.pd-hero__usp');
if ($uspElements.length > 0) {
  $(document).on('click', '.pd-hero__usp', function(){
    

    // Remove active state from all usps
    $uspElements.removeClass('pd-hero__usp--active');

    // add active state to clicked usp (not working)
    $(this).addClass('pd-hero__usp--active');
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pd-hero__usp pd-hero__usp--active">
  <div class="pd-hero__usp-icon">
    <svg class="list-point__icon list-point__iconplate" width="56" height="56" viewBox="0 0 56 56" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">[...]</svg>
  </div>
  <div class="pd-hero__usp-text">
    Text 1
  </div>
</div>
<div class="pd-hero__usp">
  <div class="pd-hero__usp-icon">
    <svg class="list-point__icon list-point__iconplate" width="56" height="56" viewBox="0 0 56 56" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">[...]</svg>
  </div>
  <div class="pd-hero__usp-text">
    Text 2
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to use following code use element $uspElements instead of targeting to document to get this context in code.

```
const $uspElements = $('.pd-hero__usp');
if ($uspElements.length > 0) {
  $uspElements.on('click', () => {
    console.log($(this)); 

    // Remove active state from all usps
    $(this).removeClass('pd-hero__usp--active');

    // add active state to clicked usp (not working)
    $(this).addClass('pd-hero__usp--active');
  });
}
```

Comment: The problem the OP has is that `this` in the callback referrers to the `document` and that's not because of the event delegation, but because of using the arrow function, so in your code `this` still referrers to `document` and the problem still persists.